# How to add packages from git to my Meteor project

Tags: git, meteor, random, package

I updated my Meteor project to 1.6.1 which no longer supports Meteor.uuid(). The package artwells:accounts-guest requires it and user [baursn](https://github.com/baursn) has submitted [a merge of a pull request](https://github.com/artwells/meteor-accounts-guest/pull/57) that updates the user of Meteor.uuid() to Random.id().

[Artwells](https://github.com/artwells) is yet to update the [main package](https://github.com/artwells/meteor-accounts-guest), so I'd like to use baursn's version. How?

Comment: Clone the fork of baursn that is displayed on the pullrequest into your package directory. If you have no local packages just create a directory outside your project and set the environment variable `METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS=path/to/directory` also don't forget to check that the version in this local package is set in your meteor packages list.

Comment: Thanks. That almost sounds like an answer, not a comment :) What's the pull request syntax? Where do I set the environment variable? I add the package to package.json in the root of my project, under 'dependencies'? How do I properly name it and version it?

Comment: An easier way is just to create a packages directory inside your project and put it in there. Nudge the version number to stop it going back to the offficial repo

Comment: Thanks @Mikkel. That sounds easier. So, I add a packages folder to my project, put the downloaded unzipped package from baursn in there. Then what?

Comment: Open the package.json file in that folder, and change the version number, eg if its 2.1.4, change it to 3.0.0 which will make this the most recent version, and then just run your project as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mikkel, in the comments above, pointed me in the right direction.

I added /packages in my project. I downloaded [baursn's package](https://github.com/baursn/meteor-accounts-guest) and, unzipped it, then put it in the new /packages folder. In that package's package.js, the version number was already set to something higher than for [the same package by Artwells](https://github.com/artwells/meteor-accounts-guest).

Then, both `meteor list` and `meteor` resulted in the following error:

```
=> Errors while initializing project:         

    While selecting package versions:
    error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency: kadira:flow-router 2.7.0, was 2.12.1.
    Constraints on package "kadira:flow-router":
    * kadira:flow-router@=2.7.0 || =2.6.2 || =2.4.0 || =2.3.0 || =2.2.0 <- brettle:accounts-patch-ui 0.1.3 <- artwells:accounts-guest 0.1.13


To allow potentially incompatible changes to top-level dependencies, you must pass --allow-incompatible-update on the command line.
```

Running meteor --allow-incompatible-update did resolve this, adding some packages and downgrading kadira:flow-router. Not ideal, but it got my project working again.

After that, I ran a `meteor update` and, then, simply `meteor`.

Comment: If you're looking for up to date version of FR, try [flow-router-extra](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/flow-router).